# Как реализовать меню-дерево с помощью радиокнопок? HTML, JS

Tags: javascript, html, меню, дерево, radiobutton

Надо сделать только с помощью радиокнопок меню-дерево в HTML и JS, т.е. чтобы при нажатии кнопки открывалось еще меню с подпунктами

Comment: Можно после каждой радиокнопки спрятать блок с подпунктами и использовать селектор типа `:checked + div { display:block }` для отображения

Comment: Можно чуть-чуть поподробней. Не понимаю, как это реализовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример простейшего варианта без JS. Если нужно чтобы раскрытие ветки меню не вызывало закрытие других веток, то можно заменить радиокнопки на чекбоксы. И, конечно, отображение самих радиокнопок можно выключить, оставив только лейблы.

```css
:not(:checked) + label + .sub-items {
  /* скрываем блок подменю под невыбранными пунктами */
  display: none;
}

.sub-items {
  margin:0.2em 0 0.2em 2em;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 2em);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="item" id="item-1"><label for="item-1">Пункт 1</label>
<div class="sub-items">
  <input type="radio" name="sub-item-1" id="sub-item-1-1"><label for="sub-item-1-1">Подпункт 1.1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sub-item-1" id="sub-item-1-2"><label for="sub-item-1-2">Подпункт 1.2</label>
</div>

<input type="radio" name="item" id="item-2"><label for="item-2">Пункт 2</label>
<div class="sub-items">
  <input type="radio" name="sub-item-2" id="sub-item-2-1"><label for="sub-item-2-1">Подпункт 2.1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sub-item-2" id="sub-item-2-2"><label for="sub-item-2-2">Подпункт 2.2</label>
</div>

<input type="radio" name="item" id="item-3"><label for="item-2">Пункт 3</label>
<div class="sub-items">
  <input type="radio" name="sub-item-3" id="sub-item-3-1"><label for="sub-item-3-1">Подпункт 3.1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sub-item-3" id="sub-item-3-2"><label for="sub-item-3-2">Подпункт 3.2</label>
</div>
```